# Latest kernel version crashes on boot. How to investigate?

Tags: 10.04, kernel

I have AMD Athlon XP1600+ with 623 MB of ram.

It was running fine with kernel `2.6.32-31-generic` until I installed the latest updates. After updating Ubuntu requested to restart the computer. As soon as the computer  boots, the system crashes immediately, starting up, crashing, also.

When a key is pressed, the Grub menu appears. After selecting the `kernel 2.6.32-31-generic` the system boots normally.

Both `2.6.32-32` entries (normal and recovery) are crashing. There are no visible entries in the log-files made. What can go wrong? How can I figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Current Version is not 2.26.... but uname -a
Linux Ubuntu-Bernard 2.6.32-31-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 18:24:35 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux. I can successfully boot from a live-cd with a more recent kernel, eg. Linux Mint: uname -a
Linux mint 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Try removing `quiet` from the `linux` line in the Grub boot entry, and report the last few messages you see on the screen. If you're feeling more ambitious, check the [kernel debugging guides](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging).

Comment: Gilles. Thank you very much for your advice. I removed "quiet" as well as "splash" and added the tag "debug". After pressing Ctrl-x the computer crashes instantaneous.  (No logfile /tmp/initramfs-debug was created).

Comment: I checked the boot-directory for potential "abnormal" files. Everything seems fine. The config-files of both kernels have only a slight difference :diff config-2.6.32-31-generic  config-2.6.32-32-generic 
3,4c3,4
< # Linux kernel version: 2.6.32-31-generic
< # Fri Apr  8 18:24:23 2011
---
> # Linux kernel version: 2.6.32-32-generic
> # Wed Apr 20 21:54:15 2011
74c74
< CONFIG_VERSION_SIGNATURE="Ubuntu 2.6.32-31.61-generic 2.6.32.32+drm33.14"
---
> CONFIG_VERSION_SIGNATURE="Ubuntu 2.6.32-32.62-generic 2.6.32.38+drm33.16"
124c124
< CONFIG_NET_NS=y
---
> # CONFIG_NET_NS is not set

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).